how to end a connection in Socket library in python program after 2 seconds
I am trying to run the script. But when I pass an IP which is not in the network to the s.connect() function. It dosen't respond, the script goes on hold, so I want to end the check on IP, if the Ip is not found in the network. Does anyone have an idea, on how to proceed.
import socket
def getBanner(ip,port):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)
    if(s.connect((ip,port))):
        banner = s.recv(1024).decode()
        return banner
    else:
        return "Nothing"

def main():
    ip = "192.168.152."+str(0)
    banner = getBanner(ip,21)
    print(banner)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
main()


setdefaulttimeout only applies to sockets created after the call. And you really shouldn't use a global socket in case you want to call getBanner a second time. And as long as nag-mode is on, recv may receive partial data, causing .decode to fail. And how about closing that socket?

Are you really trying to connect to port 21 (FTP)?

To end a connection in the Socket library in Python after a specified timeout period, you can set a timeout value on the socket object using the settimeout() method. Here's how you can modify your code to end the connection after 2 seconds:
import socket

def getBanner(ip, port):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(2)  # Set timeout to 2 seconds
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024).decode()
        return banner
    except socket.timeout:
        return "Connection timed out"
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        return "Connection refused"
    except Exception as e:
        return "Error: " + str(e)
    finally:
        s.close()

def main():
    ip = "192.168.152." + str(0)
    banner = getBanner(ip, 21)
    print(banner)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

